# How do I stop QGIS from crashing when trying to create a DEM from a contour line file?

Tags: qgis-3, dem

I am trying to use the same methodology I have used in the past to create a DEM from a line shapefile containing contours. However, it keeps crashing when I follow this methodology. (Using QGIS 3.10.9 with GRASS 7.8.3.)

I load the Mapset and then use v.in.ogr.qgis to create the output vector file. It seems to finish successfully although it gives warnings that say "file not found for location." I'm not quite sure what file it is talking about. This is the dialog it generates:

```
file not found for location  
Over-riding projection check  
Check if OGR layer "contours" contains polygons...
file not found for location
Creating attribute table for layer "contours" ...  
Default driver / database set to:  
driver: sqlite
database: $GISDBASE/$LOCATION_NAME/$MAPSET/sqlite/sqlite.db  
Importing 31 features (OGR layer "contours")...  
Building topology for vector map "contours_vector@POCC"...
Registering primitives...
Successfully finished
```

Then I use v.to.rast.attr and use the output vector file as the name of the input vector map. That filename shows up in the dropdown box, but when I select it, the program hangs up and a minute later it says "QGIS unexpectedly crashed."  I did look at the attribute table for the output vector file and noticed that it did not contain the contour values, just a column labeled "cat". I don't know if this is normal or not.

There may be something I'm not setting correctly, but I don't know what it might be. Any ideas?

I don't know if the stack trace is of any help, and I'm not quite sure how to keep all of the text from running together but here is the stack trace.

```
RtlRaiseStatus :
 ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string' :
longjmp :
G_fatal_error :
G_getenv :
db_read_dbmscap :
db_start_driver :
db_start_driver_open_database :
QgsGrassVectorLayer::fields qgsgrassvector.cpp:124
QgsGrassModuleInput::currentFields qgsgrassmoduleinput.cpp:1076
QgsGrassModuleVectorField::updateFields qgsgrassmoduleparam.cpp:1120
QMetaObject::activate :
QgsGrassModuleInput::onLayerChanged qgsgrassmoduleinput.cpp:1242
QMetaObject::activate :
QWidgetLineControl::`default constructor closure' :
QComboBox::setCurrentIndex :
QComboBox::setCurrentIndex :
QWidgetLineControl::`default constructor closure' :
QMetaObject::activate :
QAbstractItemModel::endInsertRows :
QStandardItemModel::insertRows :
QStandardItem::insertRow :
QStandardItemModel::insertRow :
QComboBox::insertItem :
QgsGrassModuleInput::onChanged qgsgrassmoduleinput.cpp:1180
QMetaObject::activate :
QComboBox::qt_static_metacall :
QMetaObject::activate :
QLineEdit::qt_static_metacall :
QMetaObject::activate :
QWidgetLineControl::finishChange :
QWidgetLineControl::internalSetText :
QComboBox::setCurrentIndex :
QComboBox::setCurrentIndex :
QgsGrassModuleInputComboBox::hidePopup qgsgrassmoduleinput.cpp:606
QComboBoxPrivateContainer::eventFilter :
QCoreApplicationPrivate::sendThroughObjectEventFilters :
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper :
QApplication::notify :
QgsApplication::notify qgsapplication.cpp:418
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
QApplicationPrivate::sendMouseEvent :
QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy :
QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy :
QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper :
QApplication::notify :
QgsApplication::notify qgsapplication.cpp:418
QCoreApplication::notifyInternal2 :
QGuiApplicationPrivate::processMouseEvent :
QWindowSystemInterface::sendWindowSystemEvents :
QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents :
UserCallWinProcCheckWow :
DispatchMessageWorker :
QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents :
qt_plugin_query_metadata :
QEventLoop::exec :
QCoreApplication::exec :
main main.cpp:1606
BaseThreadInitThunk :
RtlUserThreadStart :


QGIS Info  
QGIS Version: 3.10.9-A Coru�a  
QGIS code revision: bf47e9d3e1  
Compiled against Qt: 5.11.2  
Running against Qt: 5.11.2  
Compiled against GDAL: 3.0.4  
Running against GDAL: 3.0.4  

System Info  
CPU Type: x86_64  
Kernel Type: winnt  
Kernel Version: 6.1.7601
```